# How to filter and process on a dataframe for some different conditions and combine them without using for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, group-by

I have a dataframe of logs of orders for anything and a list of times. at moment t, each order can be active or deactive and it can calculate such as below:

```
create_time <= t < response time
```

I want to calculate sum of active orders value for each item at each moment that are in my moment list and store all of them in a dataframe.

**orders dataframe:**

| id | create_time | response_time | value | item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09:00:00 | 10:00:00 | 100 | y |
| 2 | 08:00:00 | 09:00:00 | 200 | x |
| 3 | 10:00:00 | 11:45:00 | 300 | x |
| 4 | 09:40:00 | 09:43:00 | 400 | y |
| 5 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | 500 | w |
| 6 | 11:15:00 | 14:00:00 | 250 | x |
| 7 | 07:00:00 | 07:12:00 | 10 | z |
| 8 | 05:00:00 | 15:00:00 | 350 | y |

**moment list:**

**08:00:00 - 08:30:00 - 9:00:00 - 09:30:00 - 10:00:00 - ...**

**my desired output:**

| moment | item | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 08:00:00 | x | 200 |
| 08:00:00 | y | 350 |
| 08:30:00 | x | 200 |
| 08:30:00 | y | 350 |
| 09:00:00 | y | 100+350=450 |
| 09:30:00 | y | 100+350=450 |
| 10:00:00 | x | 300 |
| 10:00:00 | y | 350 |

**code for create order dataframe and moment list:**

```py
id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
create_time = ['09:00:00', '08:00:00', '10:00:00', '09:40:00', '12:00:00', '11:15:00', '07:00:00', '05:00:00']
response_time = ['10:00:00', '09:00:00', '11:45:00', '09:43:00', '13:00:00', '14:00:00', '07:12:00', '15:00:00']
value = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 250, 10, 350] 
item = ['y', 'x', 'x', 'y', 'w', 'x', 'z', 'y']
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'create_time': create_time, 'response_time': response_time, 'value': value, 'item': item})

moment_list = ['08:00:00', '08:30:00', '9:00:00', '09:30:00', '10:00:00']
```

my sulotion is using for such as below:

```py
import pandas as pd


a = pd.DataFrame()
for moment in moment_list:
    moment_df = df[(df.create_time <= moment) & (df.response_time > moment)]
    moment_df = df.groupby('item')['value'].sum().reset_index()
    a = pd.concat([moment_df, a])
print(a)
```

this is the simple form of my problem. I have a large dataframe and big list of moments also I need to apply some many filters to create my moment dataframe in for loop.

Can anyone help me and introduce a faster way for this because my for loop is a litlle slow.

Comment: Why me? NB. If you want a greater chance to get a response, provide a reproducible input as DataFrame constructor and the explicit expected output (in my case for example, it's a pain to copy the data when I'm on my phone, so if too tricky I don't answer).

Comment: @mozway. Because you are famous :)

Comment: Please provide the expected output for your sample.

Comment: @mozway Thanks for your guidance. I add them to question. if it is possible, please answer :)

Comment: @Corralien I added them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocessing data, make sure the comparability of time-related columns.

```
moment_list = ['08:00:00', '08:30:00', '9:00:00', '09:30:00', '10:00:00']
moment_series = pd.Series(moment_list)
moment_series = pd.to_datetime(moment_series, format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
moment_series
###
0    08:00:00
1    08:30:00
2    09:00:00
3    09:30:00
4    10:00:00
dtype: object
```

```
df['create_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['create_time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
df['response_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['response_time'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time
df
###
   id create_time response_time  value item
0   1    09:00:00      10:00:00    100    y
1   2    08:00:00      09:00:00    200    x
2   3    10:00:00      11:45:00    300    x
3   4    09:40:00      09:43:00    400    y
4   5    12:00:00      13:00:00    500    w
5   6    11:15:00      14:00:00    250    x
6   7    07:00:00      07:12:00     10    z
7   8    05:00:00      15:00:00    350    y
```

---

```
df_array = df[['create_time', 'response_time']].to_numpy()
df_3d_array = np.tile(df_array, (len(moment_series),1,1))
```

`create_time ≤ t < response_time`

```
cross_boolean = ((df_3d_array[:,:,0] <= np.tile(moment_series, (len(df),1)).T) & (np.tile(moment_series, (len(df),1)).T < df_3d_array[:,:,1])).T
cross_boolean
###
[[False False  True  True False]
 [ True  True False False False]
 [False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]]
```

**You may wanna check after `df[moment_series] = cross_boolean`, how `df` looks like.**

```
df[moment_series] = cross_boolean
output = df.melt(id_vars=['item','value'], value_vars=moment_series, var_name='moment', value_name='boolean')
output = output[output['boolean'] == True]
output.drop(columns=['boolean'], inplace=True)
```

Output

```
output_group = output.groupby(['moment','item']).sum().reset_index()
output_group
###
     moment item  value
0  08:00:00    x    200
1  08:00:00    y    350
2  08:30:00    x    200
3  08:30:00    y    350
4  09:00:00    y    450
5  09:30:00    y    450
6  10:00:00    x    300
7  10:00:00    y    350
```

Comment: thank you veru much. I think you first create a 3D matrix for detect at each moment, whicg orders are active. Are you sure it is faster than my for loop in a large dataframe???I have to many orders and moment to check and it cause 3Dmatrix become very very big

Comment: Faster but it depends on the quantity of the `moment` list, if it only contains a little, and says `10`, it won't hurt using the looping approach.

Comment: but I have 60 moment at each hour and 8 hours in each dat and about 20 days in every running algorithm. len(moment) = 20*8*60

Comment: If the unique `moment` is up to 20*8*60, and it's a routine job(cron), then it is worth deploying them with matrix manipulation.

Comment: Thanks
If you have a better way, tell me please

Comment: You may ask for better solution in your main reply section. These guys all really good at numpy、pandas